# Submit data to PHP, and get the result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to submit some data. Weather this be using a form, or `onClick` execute some AJAX, I'm not sure.

For example, I have this input

```
<input id='inpamount' type="text" name="amount" value="2.00" onkeyup="pad();validatemin();product()">
```

Now say if I wanted to send this data to a PHP file, using post ( i could just add a form). But then, without reloading the page (I can do this), how could I fetch a response (using AJAX).

Essentially I would like a user to be able to press a button, then to submit the inputs to a php file, and then get the output and assign it to a variable (I know how to do this, I just want to be able to get the data.

The php execute takes a few centiseconds because it comunicates with SQL. (If this matters).

I have considered using invisible forms but it didn't seem to work

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: A simple google search would get you this-
https://jonsuh.com/blog/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return

Comment: Send it with ajax,  https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

       $('#inpamount').click(function() {

            var data = 'myValue=' + $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "yourscript.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function(scriptOutput) {
                   //handle the result
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Looks good man! What about session data, say if I send the request, in the php, can I refer to session data of the user who submitted it?

Comment: Not sure if i understood you correctly, but in the script which handles your ajax request (yourscript.php in the example) you can call `session_start()` which as allows you to access the correspondig session data.